# Le pronom « y » dans « s'y connaître en »

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, verbes

Selon *Advanced French Grammar* (p. 147) de V. Mazet.

s'**y** connaître en [= Être habile, expert en quelque chose ; s'**y** entendre](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionaries/french/se_conna%C3%AEtre/18280?q=connaitre#18175)
= [cette définition sur Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/conna%C3%AEtre)

Exemples :

> S'**y** connaître en peinture.
>
> Tu t'**y** connais en (tortues) ?

Quel est l'antécédent du pronom **y** ?

Pourquoi n'existe-t-il pas également *s'y savoir en* ?

Comment: Lorsqu'on cite un extrait la moindre des choses est de reporter précisément le contenu du texte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"S'y connaître" est une tournure familière qui s'est substituée à la tournure originale qui est "se connaître à/en quelque chose".
Le *y* dans "s'y connaître" a donc remplacé le "à/en quelque chose" de la tournure originale, que pour ainsi dire plus personne n'emploie aujourd'hui.

Normalement, ajouter "en quelque chose" après "s'y connaître" est donc un non-sens, puisque le "y" est censé faire référence à quelque chose qui a déjà été évoqué.
Il faudrait donc dire :

> Il se connaît en voitures.
>
> Les voitures ? Il s'y connaît.

Cela dit, la tournure pléonastique "s'y connaître en quelque chose" est totalement passée dans le langage courant, au point qu'elle a supplanté la tournure originale correcte.

Comment: Cela dit, ça reste du langage parlé. Je déconseille fortement d'écrire "s'y connaître en quelque chose" dans un document formel.

Comment: @Lamine également : Je vous suis reconnaissant et ai plussoyé. Je vous souhaite la bienvenue, Yves la France !

Answer (score 0):

"S'y connaître en peinture" est aussi vulgaire que "Savoir y faire avec les filles" et c'est une tournure incorrecte.

"Il connaît bien la peinture", voire "Il est passionné de peinture" sont proches et corrects.

Comment: Je ne vois pas en quoi "s'y connaitre en" est vulgaire, familier pourquoi pas mais il est passé dans le langage courant depuis trop longtemps pour pouvoir être qualifié d'incorrect. Le dictionnaire de l'Académie cite d'ailleurs: "Vous connaissez-vous à cela? Je m'y connais mieux que vous." http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/conna%25C3%25AEtre

Comment: Votre exemple n'est pas convaincant : la réponse "je m'y connais mieux que vous", réponse à la question assez littéraire "vous connaissez-vous à cela", n'est pas assimilable à "je m'y connais en peinture". C'est le "en peinture" qui est vulgaire et peu correct.